# C++ Sub array offset from an existing array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I would like to create a sub array which is offset from the original array without copying the contents.

i.e

```
byte* arr = new byte[4];
//0...3 meaning 0 through 3
arr[0...3] = 1...4

byte* subarr = arr+2;
```

So that `subarr[0]` is equal to 3. This actually does work; if I print `subarr[0]` I get 3. However if I want to use it in a function such as `memcpy()`, I get an error:

There isn't actually an error message, but the breakpoint is in free_base.cpp. The breakpoint in my code is at `memcpy`. The actual use case is:

```
byte* tempbuffer = new byte[size+2];
ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, (PBYTE*)(moduleStart + offset - 1), tempbuffer, size+2, 0);

byte* subbuffer = tempbuffer + 1;
assert(subbuffer[0] == tempbuffer[1]);
memcpy(out_buffer, subbuffer, size);

delete[] subbuffer;
delete[] tempbuffer;
```

I know the sub array in this example is redundant because I can literally just pass the buffer into `ReadProcessMemory` however this was just to find the bug. If I pass `out_buffer` (which is an LPVOID) directly to `ReadProcessMemory` I get valid results and no errors. Also if I use `memcpy` on `tempbuffer` (the original array), it also gives me what I want with no errors. So the error must be caused by the sub array and using `memcpy` on it.

Why is this happening and what can I do as an alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the definition of out_buffer?  what is the length of it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a sub-array. You are performing basic pointer arithmetic. What is your question, actually?

Comment: `out_buffer` is from `DWORD var1` then `&var1` as passed through the parameters of a function where the param for `out_buffer` is `LPVOID out_buffer`. The length of `out_buffer` would be `sizeof(DWORD)` or 32 bits. It is the same as the variable `size`.

@LightnessRacesinOrbit My question is, how can I use `memcpy` where the source array is offset?

Comment: @user2513924: The same way you do when it's not?

Comment: I think the error comes from `delete[] subbuffer;` You shouldn't destroy anything not comming directly from `new`.

Comment: gdlmx is probably right. Still, if you have a question about an error, you need to present your [MCVE] before we move to answer it. As it stands, you didn't even tell us what the error you're asking about _is_.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @gdlmx , but deleting the line still comes up with the error.

The problem is, there is no error message. Just a breakpoint. The error box is literally "There was an exception." and it takes me to free_base.cpp.

Comment: memcpy doesn't know anything about overlapping blocks, for your purposes it is safety to use memmove.

Comment: Seems that you're using a debugger, is it a way to catch the exception and display some useful message? It is very hard to spot the problem without knowing what kind of exception you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code regarding the sub buffer is fine, the reason there is an error occuring in your debugger is because you're calling delete[] on subbuffer.  You should not be doing that, you only need to delete[] on tempbuffer because that's the only var that was created with new.  I tested your code and verified this.